# Cocoon links are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I user Rails 4 and Cocoon gem.
In fact, I know the problem - cocoon.js is not compiled into application.js as I can see in the browser. I do require cocoon in application.js and have the gem installed.

I do not use turbolinks.
What else might cause this?

Comment: `I know the problem - cocoon.js is not compiled into application.js as I can see in the browser`, In production or development?

Comment: Production, assets served via Nginx

Comment: Have you recompiled your assets before deploying? How do you deploy?

Comment: I have nginx docker container serve /app/assets/*.
It's surprising for me, since other JS libraries do work ok.

Comment: You should never serve directly from your `/app/assets` folder - this is only for development. You should always precompile your assets and serve `/public` folder instead.

Comment: Ok, noted. Still does not answer the question why other JS libs are working ok and compiled into application.js and cocoon is not.

Comment: I am really surprised that anything got compiled into application.js - that is a result of precompilation process. Is your website available publicly? If so, could you give the link?

Comment: No, it's not public. I've turned precompilation on. Now I have cocoon with digest compiled to /public/assets. I have it accessible via Nginx. But clicking on add_association doe s not call anything.

Comment: Accessible via nginx is not the same as available in your application. Does the script actually get requested by the browser when the page loads?

Comment: @BroiSatse - thnx, was my bad w/ nginx configuration.

Comment: please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from the developer of cocoon.

> Good news! Tips for the future: do not do `rake assets:precompile` in development, because I have noticed weird effects with that too. And to really clean the assets, you have to do `rake assets:clobber` (clean leaves the last three compilations and deletes the older ones).

I hope it helps.